# curropted.xlsx file created with error- Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook(java.io.FileOutputStream)

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

with the below code, am trying to create one output .xlsx file in the project path, with one sheet creation and header assignment. file getting created with 0kb. while opening the file it gives message as "the file format or file extension is not valid. verify the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."
Also soap ui gives error message as "Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook(java.io.FileOutputStream)"

//code for creation of file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*;
import jxl.*; 
import jxl.write.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.* ;

def groovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
def projectPath = groovyUtils.projectPath 


//creating the output sheet 
FileOutputStream outfile = new FileOutputStream(new File(projectPath+"\\"+outputFileName));
XSSFWorkbook writableWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(outfile);
XSSFSheet writableSheet = writableWorkbook.createSheet("Output Sheet");

Row header = writableSheet.createRow(0);
header.createCell(0).setCellValue("TestCase");
header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Parameter");
header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Actual");
header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Expected");
header.createCell(4).setCellValue("Status");

context["Outputdata"]=writableSheet 

writableWorkbook.write();
writableWorkbook.close();
```

> stack trace:
>
> Tue Dec 26 13:50:10 GMT+05:30 2017:ERROR:groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook(java.io.FileOutputStream)
>      groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook(java.io.FileOutputStream)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1550)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1404)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:46)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
>       at Script19.run(Script19.groovy:72)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:211)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:47)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:138)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:46)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:128)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: As the error states there is not a constructor for [XSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) using a `FileOutputStream` as the parameter. A `XSSFWorkbook` only can be constructed by reading from a `InputStream` or as new empty workbook without parameter. Only writing the workbook using `Workbook.write(java.io.OutputStream stream)` is possible. See [Reading and Rewriting Workbooks](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook).

Comment: Try `XSSFWorkbook writableWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(projectPath + "\\" + outputFileName))
`

Comment: @aristotl: its giving error as Tue Dec 26 14:55:30 GMT+05:30 2017:ERROR:java.io.FileNotFoundException: X:\Soap Projects\Output_getConsFldPersonSearch.xlsx (The system cannot find the file specified). I am trying to create the above file and assign headers and values to it.

Comment: @AxelRichter: I tried to the below code (reference used reading and rewriting workbooks) code: "Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();" Error:Tue Dec 26 15:01:15 GMT+05:30 2017:ERROR:org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Name: /xl/workbook.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml' with class 'org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook' to class 'jxl.Workbook'

Comment: The `Workbook` in `apache poi` code examples is always [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html) and not `jxl.Workbook`. `Apache poi` and `JXL` are two different libraries. You cannot mixing them.

Comment: @AxelRichter: thank you for our detailed observation. its working fine now with below piece of code "XSSFWorkbook WritableWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook()
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(projectPath+"\\"+outputFileName))"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of above code, if the below one is used, file gets created successfully with the headers created.

```
XSSFWorkbook WritableWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook() FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(projectPath+"\\"+outputFileName))
```